# pickatedate.js disable dates not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, pickadate

I have a calendar using pickadate.js. After it is initialized, I am trying to run some front-end commands, I got picking a date to work using:

```
$('.arrives.picker__input').pickadate('set').set('select', [arrivalYear, arrivalMonth, arrivalDay]);
```

But I am unable to disable dates. I used

```
$('.arrives.picker__input').pickadate('set').set('disable', [[2016,8,6],[2016,8,13]]);
```

and

```
$('.arrives.picker__input').pickadate({
  disable: [
    { from: [2016,7,14], to: [2016,7,27] }
  ]
});
```

I dont get any errors, but I dont see any dates disabled..

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked for me disabling the days in August. The only difference is in my code I did not have the semicolon at the end.

I was testing:

```
disable: [
    { from: [2016,7,14], to: [2016,7,27] }
  ]   code.
```